# How do you fix Qt console output on windows (using `qInstallMsgHandler` and `qDebug`)?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, debugging, console

Background:

I am using Qt's `qInstallMsgHandler()` and `qDebug()` and this is a GUI application.

My message handler is identical to the example message handler given in Qt's [`qtglobal::qInstallMsgHandler()` documentation here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler).

Linux versus Windows:

On Linux, each time `qDebug()` is called the messages are displayed to the console immediately... and this is good and expected.

On Windows, each time `qDebug()` is called the messages are NOT displayed to the console. Instead nothing shows up in the console. Then when the application closes all the messages show up in the console suddenly.

The question:

**How do you fix Qt console output on windows (using `qInstallMsgHandler()` and `qDebug()`)?**

Answer (score 3):

**On Windows, the message handler needs to have `fflush(stderr)` executed after `fprintf()`.** Not sure why you need this extra `fflush()` but it works.

---

The long story:

I happened to notice that before calling qInstallMsgHandler() the qDebug() messages actually do appear immediately after each call to qDebug().

On a hunch I decided to look into qDebug() function. I happened to have Qt built from source on Windows and so I went into the qDebug() source code and found that if there is not a message handler then they have a default message handler short snippet of code. Here's essentially what this snippet is:

```
if (handler) {
    (*handler)(msgType, buf);
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", buf);
    fflush(stderr);
}
```

I added `fflush(stderr)` to my message handler and now the qDebug() messages do appear as they come.

---

Caveat from Qt documentation about qDebug():

> Under Windows, the message is sent to the console, **if [your application] is a
>   console application; otherwise [if your application is a GUI application], [your message] is sent to the debugger**. This
>   function does nothing if QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT was defined during
>   compilation.

(Note: Emphasis added by me. Text in square braces is my own.)